# Flutter same container different content animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-text, flutter-container, flutter-module

In a container widget I am showing a text widget for displaying content. I am using same container but the text content differs based on user selection. when user choose different option is it possible to fade the old content and show new content with animation.

```
    String content = "content";
    String subcontent = "subContent";

    switch (contentType) {
      case 1:
        content = "content1";
        subcontent = "subContent1";
        break;case 2:
     content = "content2";
        subcontent = "subContent2";
        break;case 3:
      content = "content3";
        subcontent = "subContent3";
        break;
      default:
        constantDataName = "content1";
        subcontentFieldName = "subContent1";
        break;
    }

return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25), bottomRight: Radius.circular(25)),
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.03999999910593033), offset: Offset(0, 1), spreadRadius: 5, blurRadius: 10)],
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(content1),const SizedBox(height: 10),Text(subcontent1),],
      ),
    );
```

Thanks,

Comment: yes it is possible, please include you code so can help you

Comment: code added. please check

Comment: please check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `AnimatedSwitcher`, the Important think you should attend to is that use `UniqueKey()`, try this:

```
class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListWidget> createState() => _ListWidgetState();
}

class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> {
  List _list = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
  ];
  String _maintText = 'select your number';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              key: UniqueKey(), // <---- very important part
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                _maintText,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _maintText = _list[index];
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(_list[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: _list.length,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]